# Amazing bug with Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I am a beginner in Eclipse CDT. I recently have an amazing bug that I am not able to figure out. In fact, when I debug my application, it correctly work without any problem. But when I run it, It crashes and I am able to know the origin of this problem since It does not appear in debug mode. Please help me. Thanks you in advance

S.T.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can't detect logic errors. Check for the things like NULL pointers, infinite loops, etc.

If you can post your code here, do it. So we can help better.

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your answer. I've finally located the error. It seems that there is a problem of pointers. In fact I create a boost shared_ptr (ptr) which encapsulate a C-structure. So when I want to pass a pointer of the C-structure as input to a function, I call ptr.get() and my program crashs. How can I solved this problem? Thanks you

Comment: try using `&pointer_name` instead of `ptr.get()`. I'm not sure if this will work, but give it a try.